# Inserting a child node when list is empty (XForms)

Tags: insert, xforms

My problem is the following :

I usually have those data:

```
<structures>
    <structure id="10">
      <code>XXX</code>
    </structure>
</structures>
```

so the table I display (single columns : code) is ok.

But in some cases, the data is the result a a query with no content, so the data is:

```
    <structures/>
```

resulting in my table not displaying + error.

I am trying to insert, in the case of an empty instance, a single node so that the data would look like:

```
<structures>
    <structure id="0"/>
</structures>
```

I am trying something like that :

```
<xforms:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done">
    <xforms:insert if="0 = count(instance('{./instance-name}')/root/node())" context="instance('{./instance-name}')/root/node()" origin="xforms:element('structure', '')" /> 
</xforms:action>
```

but no node inserted when I look at the data in the inspector in the page.

Any obvious thing I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be erros in your XPath `if` and `context` expressions:

```
if="0 = count(instance('{./instance-name}')/root/node())"
context="instance('{./instance-name}')/root/node()"
```

You are a using curly brackets `{` and `}`, I assume to have the behavior of attribute value templates (AVTs). But the `if` and `context` expressions are already XPath expressions, so you cannot use AVTs in them. Try instead:

```
if="0 = count(instance(instance-name)/root/node())"
context="instance(instance-name)/root/node()"
```

Also, the `instance-name` path is relative to something which might not be clear when reading or writing the expression. I would suggest using an absolute path for example `instance('foo')/instance-name` to make things clearer.

You don't provide the structure of the other instances, so I can tell for sure, but you'll expression above suppose that they have the form:

```
<xf:instance id="foo">
    <some-root-element>
        <root>
            <structure/>
        </root>
    <some-root-element>
</xf:instance>
```

I don't know if that's what you intend.

Finally, you could replace `count(something) = 0`, with `empty(something)`.